# Debugging generics in Lazarus IDE

Tags: lazarus

I have this:

```
TDictionaryStrInt = specialize TFPGMap<string, integer>;
```

Can somebody tell me how the heck can I debug the Map, the Key/Value pairs?

I just see only reference to a memory address, but I really need to see the items.

Watch, local variables does not helps me.

I can see only this:

```
<TDictionaryStrStr> = {
  <TFPSMAP> = {
     <TFPSLIST> = {
       <TOBJECT> = {
         _vptr$ = {
           0x5612ec, 
           0x230b988}}, 
      FLIST = , 
      FCOUNT = 1, 
      FCAPACITY = 4, 
      FITEMSIZE = 8}, 
     FKEYSIZE = 4, 
     FDATASIZE = 4, 
    FDUPLICATES = DUPIGNORE, 
    FSORTED = false, 
    FONKEYPTRCOMPARE = $426b70 <TFPGMAP$2$CRC36DB32B4__KEYCOMPARE>, 
    FONDATAPTRCOMPARE = $523e30 
 <FGL$_$TFPSMAP_$__$$_BINARYCOMPAREDATA$POINTER$POINTER$$LONGINT>}, 
  FONKEYCOMPARE = $0, 
  FONDATACOMPARE = $0}
```